# How do I remove null elements from an ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have been trying to remove null entries from an ArrayList without success.

First, I store all words from a file into an ArrayList using specific delimiters (punctuation and whitespace).

Then I attempt to remove null entries from the ArrayList.

When I print the whole list, the null entries are still there.

How can I solve this?

```
            ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                words.add(scanner.next());
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
                if (words.get(i) == null)
                {
                    words.remove(i);
                }
            }
```

Example of current output:

```
[10, years, , , 3, Lec, , , 3, Lab, , , , Coordinating, Board, Academic, Approval, Number, 1102015707, ]
```

Example of desired output:

```
[10, years, 3, Lec, 3, Lab, Coordinating, Board, Academic, Approval, Number, 1102015707]
```

Comment: Those aren't `null` elements (if they were `null` you would be seeing the word "null" in the output). Likely they're empty `String`s. Doing something like `words.removeIf(String::isEmpty)` might work for you.

Comment: One problem is that after you've removed (say) element 3, you're still incrementing `i` (to 4) but the *previous* element 4 is now element 3, and you're not checking it. The typical ways of fixing that are either to decrement `i` after calling `words.remove(i)`, or go from the *end* of the list towards the start (so `for (int i = words.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)`).

Answer (score 1):

Try looping backwards:

```
        for (int i = words.size(); --i >= 0; ) {
            if (words.get(i) == null)
            {
                words.remove(i);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

1. Your list doesn't contain any `null` elements. If there were `null` elements in the list, then you'd be seeing output like this:

   ```
   [10, years, null, null, 3, Lec, null, null, 3, Lab, null, null, null, Coordinating, Board, Academic, Approval, Number, 1102015707, null]
   ```

   What you're most likely seeing is *empty* strings (`""`), or possibly *blank* strings (i.e., strings that contain only whitespace).
2. You're incrementing `i` even when you remove an element. The problem with this is explained in [John Skeet's comment under your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75370067/how-do-i-remove-null-elements-from-an-arraylist-in-java#comment132991426_75370067):

   > One problem is that after you've removed (say) element 3, you're still incrementing `i` (to 4) but the *previous* element 4 is now element 3, and you're not checking it. The typical ways of fixing that are either to decrement `i` after calling `words.remove(i)`, or go from the end of the list towards the start (so `for (int i = words.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)`).

There are a few approaches you could use to fix the problem. All the code below tests if a string is blank via [`String#isBlank()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#isBlank()) (instead of testing for nulls).

**Loop Backwards**

```java
for (int i = words.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (words.get(i).isBlank()) {
        words.remove(i);
    }
}
```

**Use an Iterator**

```java
// for-loop version
for (Iterator<String> itr = words.iterator(); itr.hasNext(); ) {
    if (itr.next().isBlank()) {
        itr.remove();
    }
}

// while-loop version
Iterator<String> itr = words.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    if (itr.next().isBlank()) {
        itr.remove();
    }
}
```

**Use [`removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf(java.util.function.Predicate)), passing a [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html)**

```java
// anonymous class version
words.removeIf(new Predicate<>() {
    @Override public boolean test(String word) {
        return word.isBlank();
    }
});

// lambda "block" version
words.removeIf(word -> {
    return word.isBlank();
});

// single-expression lambda version
words.removeIf(word -> word.isBlank());

// method reference version
words.removeIf(String::isBlank);
```